# How can resize only few widgets in gridster

Tags: jquery, gridster

I need one widget- 'widgetId 0' to span upto 2 columns and other widget- 'widgetId 1' to span upto 4 columns on resize. 
below are my 2 widgets:

```
 var serialize = [
    {
        "widgetId": "0",
        "text": "Test Info",
        "description": "",
        "type": "info",
         "path":"test-info.png",
        "dataType": "TEST_INFO",
        "position": {

            "col": 1,
            "row": 1,
            "size_x": 1,
            "size_y": 2


        }
    },
    {
        "widgetId": "1",
        "title": "Test Details",
        "description": "",
        "type": "info",
        "path":"test-details.png",
        "dataType": "TEST_DETAILS",
        "position": {
            "col": 2,
            "row": 1,
            "size_x": 2,
            "size_y": 2
        }
    }]
```

How can I achieve this?

Is there any javascript function to resize a particular widget?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to be able to choose wether a widget can be resizable or not, give a look at [my answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107062/make-only-one-gridster-widget-resizable/24017652#24017652)

To achieve the "controlled" resizing you can tune the x_size, y_size, and the [max_x_size, max_y_size] parameters of the add_widget function! For example set x_size = max_x_size to prevent resizing on "x" axis", set max_x_size = x_size + "n", to have the widget resizable only up to n columns on x axis, and so on...